# How to read user emailbox using Microsoft graph api with delegate permission using access token in c# console application?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, window, console-application

I'm using Graph api to get mailbox of my users with access token, but getting following error message.

{
"error": {
"code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
"message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
}
}

Kindly help me on the above error. Really appreciate any help!!

I am using the Mail.Read delegate permission and acquiring the access token to read user mailbox

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, you can **only** read **signed-in** user's and shared mailboxes using `Mail.Read` **Delegated** permission.

When I tried to read user's mailbox by executing this query in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**, I too got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/messages
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To read any user's mailbox via Microsoft Graph API, you need to grant
> `Mail.Read` permission of **Application** type and switch to **client
> credentials** flow.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted `Mail.Read` permission of **Application** type like this:

[image]

When I ran below code in c# console application, I got **response** successfully like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var messages = await graphClient.Users["sri@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"].Messages.GetAsync();
    foreach (var message in messages.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[List messages - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)